# Extending TableView - correct use of generics

Tags: generics, javafx

TableView is defined as:

```
public class TableView<S> extends Control
```

where S is "The type of the objects contained within the TableView items list."   Simple enough.

Now let's say I want to extend TableView to add some custom stuff.  And let's say that my CustomTableView is always going to contain/display classes that implement MyInterface.
Should I be defining CustomTableView as

```
public class CustomTableView<MyInterface extends S> extends TableView<S>
```

or as

```
public class CustomTableView<MyInterface> extends TableView<S>
```

(albeit that this doesn't compile)

or should I simply leave it as

```
public class CustomTableView<S> extends TableView<S>
```

Comment: why would you want that? smells like extension for the wrong reasons

Comment: @kleopatra please can you help me understand why?   I think you're probably right based on trying it, but I don't yet have a good enough handle on generics to understand why this is a bad idea?  Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

If you want the type parameter to be upper-bounded by `MyInterface` then you should declare your subclass like so:

```java
public class CustomTableView<S extends MyInterface> extends TableView<S> { ... }
```

Note I used `S` above for consistency, but you can use any name (that's a valid Java identifier) for the type parameter.

---

As noted by Ravindra in the comments you can also do:

```java
public class CustomTableView extends TableView<MyInterface> { ... }
```

But that means all code everywhere will only know the items as `MyInterface`. You can no longer be more specific when using the class; in other words, you'll no longer be able to do something like:

```java
public class Foo {

  private CustomTableView<MyInterfaceImpl> field;

  ...
}
```

If you know you'll never need to do the above then prefer Ravindra's approach.

---

As an aside, make sure you actually need to subclass `TableView`. You should typically only subclass it if you intend to add custom *behavior*; you should typically not subclass it if you only intend to apply *configuration*. You can use a method for the latter.

Comment: How about this simple and less verbose approach? `static class CustomTableView extends TableView<MyInterface>`

Comment: @RavindraRanwala That's also possible, but means the code will only know the items as `MyInterface`. Perhaps the OP wants the ability to be more specific at use sites (e.g. declare a `CustomTableView<MyInterfaceImpl>` field/variable).

Comment: Yeah, it solely depends on the specific use case, he is addressing.